# Using file mapping and parallel to deal with large file in Linux with C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

My idea is that everytime each node map one chunk of the huge file and process it. Then it munmap this chunk and go for the next piece.

However, I always get failed on clusters (Openmpi) but run fine on my machine (mpich)

The mapping part is like this:
PAGE is a integer = 4*1000*1000 // offset must be times number of one memory page, which is 4kb.
ntask is the total number of nodes 
mytask represents the current node number
so buffer size is set to total/number of nodes (statbuf.st_size/ntask)

```
char *
mmaping (char *source)
{
     int src;
     char *sm;
     struct stat statbuf;

     if ((src = open (source, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror (" open source ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

     if (fstat (src, &statbuf) < 0)
    {
        perror (" fstat source ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

      sm = mmap (0,(long long)statbuf.st_size/ntask, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE,src, mytask*share*PAGE);

      if (MAP_FAILED == sm)
      {
          perror (" mmap source ");
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      printf("length->%d\n",strlen(sm));

      return sm;
      }

error msg

[kalkyl3:15871] *** Process received signal ***
[kalkyl3:15871] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[kalkyl3:15871] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Indent your code, so we can actually read it.

Comment: You should probably call getpagesize() instead of assuming 4kB pages.  In any case, a kilobyte is 1024 bytes, not 1000.  Are you sure there is a null byte at the end of each `share*PAGE`-sized block in the file?  Because if there isn't, `strlen` will happily run off past the end of the mmaped area and segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your advice... It is heuristical. The problem comes from strlen. When i read a chunk of file, then I cannot use strlen to test its length coz you can find '\0' in this chunk.

Comment: Also, the 'PAGE' issue should also be aware of.

Comment: How about using MPI IO? That is `MPI_File_open()` and then `MPI_File_set_view()`. You should also watch out that `offset + len` of the last task still fits within the file.

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You should probably call getpagesize() instead of assuming 4kB pages. In any case, a kilobyte is 1024 bytes, not 1000. Are you sure there is a null byte at the end of each share*PAGE-sized block in the file? Because if there isn't, strlen will happily run off past the end of the mmaped area and segfault. –  Greg Inozemtsev